# How to get more voices on Yamaha Arius keyboards?

Tags: midi, keyboard, midi-controller-keyboard

I have a Yamaha Arius 144. It has a handful of voices preinstalled (harpsichord, vibraphone, etc). I'd like to get more, but I can't find any information about how to

1. get them or
2. get the keyboard to play them.

I guess this Arius 144 is similar to other midi devices so hoping there is a generic way of making this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Seems you may be stuck with the 10 voices. There's no MIDI ports, but you may be able to use the USB port to connect, via a suitable lead, to MIDI devices - which then usually need to be connected to a separate amp/speaker.

Comment: This type of keyboard has voices stored in ROM - there is no 'spare' user-space for additional voices.

Comment: > This type of keyboard has voices stored in ROM - there is no 'spare' user-space for additional voices.
Does this mean that Tim's suggestion won't work? If I understand Tim's suggestion, the setup is [keyboard -> midi device -> external speakers] ?

Comment: It means Tim's suggestion is the only that could work. It means you can't change the voices in the keyboard, as they are in Read Only Memory. Do you know if your keyboard is outputting some Midi?